# PHP + MySQL 3 Condition

Tags: php, mysql

so I have this query below in my php code :

```
$query ="SELECT * 
         FROM material_tools_master_data 
         WHERE material_name like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%' 
         ORDER BY material_code 
         LIMIT 0,50";
```

It does pretty well and give me a result called 'autocomplete' in my form. The problem is, I wanna make it more complex, I want my autocomplete filter the data selection not only by `material_name` but also with `material_tools_group` and show me exactly the `material_name` which is filtered by `material_group` = 'Measuring' OR 'Tools'.

The point is, I want to make this query works with my autocomplete. So here is my new query :

```
$query ="SELECT * 
         FROM material_tools_master_data 
         WHERE `material_tools_group` = 'Measuring' OR 'Tools' AND `material_name` like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%' 
         ORDER BY material_code LIMIT 0,50";
```

The query above is not working, the query above is giving me all the material_name rows in the table.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: What exactly do you mean in the question title by "MySQL 3"? Surely you're not actually using version 3 of MySQL, right? Not in 2016?

Comment: Your second query should throw syntax errors because you cannot do `WHERE material_tools_group = 'Measuring' OR 'Tools'`. It would have to be `WHERE (material_tools_group = 'Measuring' OR material_tools_group = 'Tools')`

Comment: @JayBlanchard, Ikr, I wanted to switch to mysqli but it takes a long time, I'll do that later because it will take a long maintenance and my client won't be happy for that. So do you have any idea to fix the problem?

Comment: @Simba, I mean '3 Condition in my sql query' not the version of MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See warnings about PHP's deprecated API, and the proper use of prepared statements above...

```
$query ="
SELECT * 
  FROM material_tools_master_data 
 WHERE material_tools_group IN('Measuring','Tools') 
   AND `material_name` LIKE '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%' 
 ORDER 
    BY material_code LIMIT 0,50;
";
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Your query seems to work, and I tried it. But however, the autocomplete shows all result from my table when I typed in the search box (material_name) but not filtered by the material_tools_group.

Comment: Nope, nevermind. After I double checked the result, your code is working! thanks again.